# Creating behavior flow report without using Google Analytics

Tags: python, pandas, analysis, clickhouse

I have to create behavior flow report without using GA because we have very large data set and we face the problem of sampling if we are using GA (in this case it creates all the reports based on ~1% of data). 
We have a table containing all the page visits done by our users.

I am not very experienced in data analysis and I can't even think of possible intermediate steps to do this. What are your suggestions?

Comment: Where exactly do you have this table with all page visits?

Comment: in clickhouse database

Comment: Could you publish the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table;` for that table?

Comment: Description is too vague, please add more details: your table, what do you want to get?